# Angular 13 to Angular 14 migration - feature modules in Angular Library project not working

Tags: angular, inject

We were putting all our feature modules in a angular library project in Angular 13.
We were lazy loading them from another angular project using routes.

When we migrate Angular from version 13 to version 14 or 15 ,
we try to load the feature modules in the angular library project we get the following error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`.
>
> Find more at [https://angular.io/errors/NG0203](https://angular.io/errors/NG0203%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0)    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:627:15)    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:638:60)    at Object.RouterModule_Factory [as useFactory] (router.mjs:443:99)    at Object.factory (core.mjs:8208:38)    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:8121:35)    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:8009:33)    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:634:33)    at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:638:60)    at useValue (core.mjs:7803:65)    at R3Injector.resolveInjectorInitializers (core.mjs:8058:17)    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1214:31)    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1168:17)    at zone.js:1281:17    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:409:31)    at core.mjs:23999:55    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23999:36)    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:408:60)    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24300:33)    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:408:60)    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)

Expectation was that the behavior of Angular 14/15 should be similar to Angular 13